# Redirect 404 from sub-folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I need/want to redirect 404 from a specific sub-folder to another page. I am using WordPress. I suspect this would likely be done using .htaccess. I am really struggling with the code. For example...

I would like **www.mydomain.com/knowledge-base/url-does-not-exist/** to redirect to **www.mydomain.com/knowledge-base/**.

Any 404 that is not associated with the sub-folder "knowledge-base" should use the default 404 page set out in WordPress.

I should note that the sub-folder "knowledge-bsae" doesn't actually exist - it is virtual.

Can someone help me with the code?

Comment: "I suspect this would likely be done using `.htaccess`" - Probably not. This sounds as if it's all part of WordPress - only WordPress knows what is (not) a valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to insert `RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ /anotherdirectory/$1 [R=301,NC,L]` to .htaccess ,  make sure there's `RewriteEngine On`, and paste the code below it.

this reference might help you [redirect directory to another](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/)

**301** is permanent and **302** is temporary for redirect.

another option is, ( i haven't tried this yet ) but you could add another .htaccess file to your subfolder, then `ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/yourcustompage` .

good luck